# CRC checking on switch

Tags: networking, switching

Sending, receiving host and router calculate CRC to check FCS field, and what about switches ? Does switch check FCS field before forward frames ? I cannot find exact answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a description](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps9441/ps9670/white_paper_c11-465436.html) of a store-and-forward switch that checks FCS before sending it on. FCS could only be done for store-and-forward, it seems, since you have to have the whole packet to calculate the FCS. But that doesn't mean all switches do this on store-and-forward.

Edit:

Also found that a switch in [cut-through mode will](http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/CEE_AG_701/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=CH_FCoE_Overview.03.4.html&single=true) forward a packet with an incorrect FCS left intact.